# Add another worksheet in an Excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabs, spreadsheet

Is it possible to include an additional set of worksheets (i.e. "tabs") into an already existing worksheet in Excel?

Comment: Posted in stackoverflow, not a programming question. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

Yes - 2 simple ways:

1. Right click any tab and select `Insert...` and then select `Worksheet`
2. From the menu bar select `Insert` and then `Worksheet`

As per the comment made to your initial post these sorts of questions are better asked on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but I made a mistake in the my question. I mean - is it possible to add set of worksheets into the worksheet ? The second level I mean.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot nest worksheets within a worksheet. You can add worksheets from one workbook into another workbook - is this what you need?

Comment: You can embed an Excel workbook (ie a 'set of worksheets') into another as an object (Insert -> Object ...), but what is the point? Maybe you should explain what is your goal.